# Use a weights argument in a list of lm lapply calls

Tags: r, lapply, lm

Here is my problem (fictional data in order to be reproducible) :

```
set.seed(42)
df<-data.frame("x"=rnorm(1000),"y"=rnorm(1000),"z"=rnorm(1000))
df2<-data.frame("x"=rnorm(100),"y"=rnorm(100),"z"=rnorm(100))
breaks<-c(-1000,-0.68,-0.01315,0.664,1000)
divider<-cut(df$x,breaks)
divider2<-cut(df2$x,breaks)
subDF<-by(df,INDICES=divider,data.frame)
subDF2<-by(df2,INDICES=divider2,data.frame)
reg<-lapply(subDF,lm,formula=x~.)
pre<-lapply(1:4,function(x){predict(reg[[x]],subDF2[[x]])})
lapply(1:4,function(x){summary(reg[[x]])$r.squared})
```

The above code works fine. What I am doing is the following : according to the values of `x`, I split `df`in 4 dataframes and run a regression on each of those dataframes, in order to be able to predict values for an other dataset. The split of the dataframe is to allow a better prediction as the range of `x` has a great impact for the actual data.

What I am trying to do is to add a weights argument for the regression to give greater importance to the most recent data. My weights argument is : `weights<-0.999^seq(250,1,by=-1)`if there are 250 data. With a seed of 42 and the previous breaks, all of the 4 dimensions are 250.

When I try to do `reg<-lapply(subDF,lm,formula=x~.,weights=0.999^seq(250,1,by=-1))`, I got this error :

```
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : 
  ..2 used in an incorrect context, no ... to look in
```

Which is quite strange as `lapply`has a `...`argument, used here for the `formula` but it doesn't accept the `weights`.

So I really don't know what to do to add those weights. What should I correct in my code or should I (almost) entirely change it to be able to use the weights ?

For the example and in order to make it (perhaps) easier, I cut the breaks so that the 4 subsets have the same dimension but ideally the answer would work even if the 4 subsets are not of the same dimension (so with breaks of `breaks<-c(-1000,-0.75,0,0.75,1000)` for instance)

[This](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/105605/forecasting-a-time-series-with-weights) post on CrossValidated has quite the same problem, but without a working solution so that didn't help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know why you got the error you got (I thought the `....`-argument was made for that. However, I found a slight workaround, is this in the direction of what you need? What I have done is created an 'anonymous' function inside lapply, which calculates the weights (dependent on dimension of data) and returns a model.

```
reg2 <- lapply(subDF, function(chunk){
  #calculate weights (!dependent on data ordering)
  weights <- 0.999^seq(nrow(chunk),1,by=-1)

  #fit model
  fit <- lm(x~., data=chunk, weights=weights)
  return(fit)
})
```

Comment: that's really great ! Maybe someone will know what the problem was but your answer is what I was looking for

Comment: You're welcome! Note that your current weights are based on the order of your dataframe. That always makes me kinda nervous, it might be safer to do something like `weights <- weights[order(data$time, decreasing=T)] or similar.

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately, you have experienced first hand the, arguably, nastiest error in R. The so-called Non-standard Evaluation (NSE) error.

After a bit of digging in the code I think I have found the culprit. Let's take things one by one:

First of all let's have a look at the `traceback()`:

```
weights <- 0.999^seq(250,1,by=-1)

lapply(subDF, lm, formula=x~., weights=weights)
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : 
  ..2 used in an incorrect context, no ... to look in
> traceback()
8: eval(expr, envir, enclos)
7: eval(extras, data, env)
6: model.frame.default(formula = ..1, data = X[[1L]], weights = ..2, 
       drop.unused.levels = TRUE)
5: stats::model.frame(formula = ..1, data = X[[1L]], weights = ..2, 
       drop.unused.levels = TRUE)
4: eval(expr, envir, enclos)
3: eval(mf, parent.frame())
2: FUN(X[[1L]], ...)
1: lapply(subDF, lm, formula = x ~ ., weights = weights)
```

It looks like the problem occurs inside the `model.frame.default`. So, let's have a look in the source code. I will not post the whole source code but if you type `model.frame.default` in the console, you will see somewhere in the middle:

```
extras <- substitute(list(...))
extranames <- names(extras[-1L])
extras <- eval(extras, data, env)
```

The last line is where it fails. The first line is what is called NSE and is created by `substitute`. `substitute` will create what is called an `expression` i.e. let's say something like an object to be evaluated (i.e. created) later inside of `eval`. As you can see in `eval`, `extras` will be evaluated in `data` and then if not found in `env`. For the formula it is ok because it is evaluated in the data and `x~.` will tell `eval` to use all the columns in `data`. `weights` though is not in the `data`. Therefore, `eval` will look for it in `env`. But what is `env`?

Apparently, `env` is an environment and is created within `model.frame.default` in the line:

```
env <- environment(formula$terms)
```

So, what does this mean? Let's see another example:

```
xtest <- function(x) {
  new_func <- function(x) {
    env <- environment(x)
    print(env)
  }
  new_func(x)
} 

> xtest(x~z)
<environment: R_GlobalEnv>
```

In the function above I try to replicate in fewer lines what `env` will be in `model.frame.default`. As you can see, `environment(formula)` points to the global environment.

So, it is there where `env` tries to find `..2` i.e. the second argument passed in `...` (i.e. `weights`), but as there is no `...` in the global environment, you got an error. Hope it is clear now!

Best solution and what I would do is use @Heroka 's answer to solve it (or you could rewrite the whole `model.frame.default` and `lm` from scratch without using NSE but I think the first is more reasonable :) ).

Comment: that's great thanks ! I also tried to do `w<-0.99^seq(1000,1,by=-1)
df<-cbind(df,w)` in order to have the weights in the data but it stills fails. Given that weights is now in the data do you know why ?

Comment: How is your `lapply` call then?

Comment: `lapply(subDF,lm,formula=x~y+z,weights=w)`

Comment: And how did you create `subDF` in order to include `w`?

Comment: given that `w`is now in `df`and `subDF`just splits `df`it also has `w` in each of the 4 `subDF[[i]]`

Comment: Thanks I will investigate.